# Repackaging an ear on RAD for WebSphere 6

Tags: java, jar, websphere, ear

I have a web application and I have updated one of the jars (digitally signed it). When I replace the old jar with the new one and restart the server the application does not feel the change.I've also tried clearing the cache.I think I need to repackage the whole ear again and then redeply it, right?
If yes would someone please tell me the steps to do so through RAD(Rational Application Developer).
I have the old ear and the new jar available

Thanks

Comment: What kind of change are you expecting? 
you are using websphere right? Replacing the jar at `websphere\installedapps\yourapp\yourwar\webinf\lib` and then restart the server. thats it

Comment: When a jar is signed and then you use the applet for the first time some security warning appears asking you to verify the signer or something like that.that doesn't happen in my case.I'll try your suggestion and let you know if it works.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

stop server -- remove the project -- start the server --add the project -- publish